# psexec with vb cannot find specified file

Tags: vb.net, psexec

I made a small program which launches an .exe on a remote computer.  When I run psexec from a CMD prompt, it works fine, when I run it in VB it errors with, "Cannot find file specified".

```
Dim targetpc As String = "192.168.1.3"
        Try
            Dim p As New Process()
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\PSTools\psexec.exe"
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\" & targetpc & " " & "C:\Program Files (x86)\AVS4YOU\AVSAudioConverter\AVSAudioConverter.exe"
            p.Start()
            p.WaitForExit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Shit didnt work")
        End Try
```

Is my concat string correct?  What am I missing here.

Comment: since you display a message when you catch the exception, you could also display the exception message. It would give you some info as to what went wrong. And add it to your post if you still don't understand... It will help other understanding your issue.

Comment: Like I said in my post, the error is "The system cannot find the file specified.  I turned off error catching and no exceptions were thrown.  Just a CMD window that pops up and displays that.  That's why I thought maybe my arugment string was missing a space or not handling spaces correctly

Comment: you end up with a few spaces in your argument `\\192.168.1.3 C:\Program Files (x86)\AVS4YOU\AVSAudioConverter\AVSAudioConverter.exe`. Try enclosing it with the character `"`

Comment: and what im saying is I can see the CMD window and I see the error.  the error is "System cant find file specified"  Im thinking ihave too many spaces or not enough?

Comment: hoki - same outcome with the enclosed "

Comment: String.Format is usually easier for this, but are you sure the file exists on the targetPC?  have you tried something like notepad or a simple popup app located in `C:\Temp` ?

Comment: Absolutely positive. If I run from cmd it works

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome all the issues listed by copying the Pstools folder form system32 into a non windows folder (i used my application install folder) then called it from there. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: please follow [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)